# Trying to fix the typical found nil while unwrapping error

Tags: swift, uitableview, uibutton

Currently I have a button in my cell thats being used as an image, why a button and not an image, it seems that using a button keeps the image sharper, but that's neither here nor there.

```
if realDistance > 8000
{
    self.tourist.text = "Tourist"

    //crashing line
    self.touristBackground.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "tours-1")

}
```

This is my current code and the commented line is the one that is crashing. I'm not sure why that's crashing but not the line above.

The exact error is fatal error:

> unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I suppose that I could try an if let but that seems to not work. I could be doing it wrong however.

EDIT. It happens here as well

```
if lbuttonHidden == true
{
    self.lls.text = String(self.lls.text!.toInt()! - 1)

    //crashing line
    if  self.lls.text ==  "\(0)"
    {
        self.trophy.image = UIImage(named: "STAR2")
    }
}
```

Comment: So which bit is nil?

Comment: The answer from @Anni S should do the trick. However I would be interested to know how "touristBackground" is declared in your class.

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
if let imageView = self.touristBackground.imageView {
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "tours-1")
}
else
{
   print("Image view is nil!")
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I tried and it still crashes with the same error.

Comment: Add class implementation and crash log error in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Given that @Anni S solution does not work (optional binding), as a way of testing, replace

```
self.touristBackground.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "tours-1")
```

With

```
self.touristBackground.imageView?.image = UIImage()
```

If your code does not crash, then the error is in the fact that (a) the image does not exist with that name or for some reason cannot be used AND (b) in your class implementation the "image" is implicitly unwrapped (cannot handle nil without crashing).